# чтение/запись и разбор байтовых посылок RS-232

Tags: c++, c

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите пожалуйста пример реализации общения с COM портом.

Читать и писать в порт RS-232 я умею. Вопрос в разборе данных на c/c++.

Нужно отслеживать начало передачи по старт-биту (0x9A), запоминать полученные данные до стоп-бита (0x7E). Как это реализовать?

То есть: я отправляю байтовый пакет и жду ответ в формате [0x9A, ...., 0x7E]. Длина ответного пакета неизвестна.

Comment: State machine и динамический буфер для приема данных.

Comment: Побайтовое чтение. Встретился  старт - чтение с записью в буфер (например, `vector<unsigned char>`). Встретился стоп - все, буфер заполнен, можно обрабатывать. Нет?

Comment: @Harry да, сам алгоритм вроде бы понятен. Но в С++ я пока не очень умею и вопрос про пример реализации.

Comment: Ну это существенно зависит от интерфейса того, как вы получаете эти самые байты из порта. Вы же как-то и куда-то их получаете? Как выглядит вызов этой функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тривиальное решение - это написать функцию, которая будет читать один байт.

```
std::uint8_t read_one_byte();
```

RS-232 очень медленный, по этому можно не заботиться о производительности чтения по одному байту.

Ошибка чтения может возвращаться при помощи исключения. Предпочтительнее использовать `std::system_error`, но можно написать свое исключение.

При помощи этой функции можно написать код, который читает строку (вектор байт):

```
while (read_one_byte() != 0x9A) /*skip*/ ;

std::vector<std::uint8_t> data;
for (;;) {
  auto byte = read_one_byte();
  if (byte == 0x7E) return;
  data.push_back(byte);
}
```

Comment: Уже реализовал у себя. Оказалось что почти так же, через вектор. Ошибки отслеживаются через CRC.